# python - is it possible to extend the set of things that xml-rpc can serialize?

Tags: python, xml-rpc

I have seen several questions asking how to send a `numpy.ndarray` through an xml-rpc call. This cannot be done out of the box because, as stated by the xml-rpc [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html), there is a fixed set of supported types, basically limited to build-ins and containers of built-ins.

A simple solution is to convert the numpy array to a list using

`<array to send>.tolist()`

on the sending side, and convert back to a numpy array using

`np.array(<list I received>)`

on the receiving side. However, suppose I want to be able to support `ndarray` directly, without explicit flattening/unflattening. Is there an interface I can implement to make this work? For example, can I extend `ndarray` (I know that's tricky) with certain flattening/unflattening methods which will be registered with xml-rpc and thus used for serialization/de-serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any hooks for extension.

Rather than flatten/unflatten, you could encode/unencode the object -- for instance using pickle, or base64-encoded pickle.

If you do flatten keep in mind that you need:

```
<array>.shape
<array>.dtype
<array>.flat
```

Simple dtypes can be converted back and forth to strings; you may need to consider complex dtypes more carefully if you want to support them.

[EDIT] To answer your question succinctly: No -- no extension hooks are available.

Comment: Sure, we can always break the array down into manageable parts. However, once we've done that, how can we possibly tell xml-rpc to unpack those parts into a proper ndarray on the receiving end? What I mean is, I can always send a tuple of (myArray.tostring(), myArray.shape, myArray.dtype) across the wire, but the receiver has no idea what to do with it.

Comment: One way of looking at it is -- even if there were extension hooks, they would have to be installed on both ends. Instead of hooks, it seems that you need to write wrappers, which have a common convention on both ends for how raw objects are annotated. One simple way to do it is that all binary objects are actually pickles: if both ends know this you still can't send everything (eg. not a bound method... unless you extend pickle -- but here there are hooks) but you should be able to send most things.

Comment: Yup. But the thing is, if we're going to do wrappers, at least for ndarray we might as well do the <myArray>.tolist() and array(<incomingList>) that I mentioned in the question. I agree that it would be possible to write a generic flatten/unflatten wrapper to handle more types.

Comment: The base64 representation will be somewhat more compact... indeed if you really want compact, then look into [blosc](http://blosc.pytables.org/trac). Or if you want readable, then toList() is probably fine (though string or structured dtype could cause problems if you don't save it).

Comment: The point of my question is really whether or not extension hooks exists, and I guess the answer is not. Wrappers it is.

Comment: shaunc: The only reason I haven't accepted your answer is that it doesn't definitively say whether or not there are extensibility hooks.

Comment: (Daniel -- did you notice the edit? I even took a quick look at the source code -- no hooks in sight...)